# В чем проблема с использованием алиасов?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

я настроил алиасы следующим образом

```
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["utils/*"],
      "@UI/*": ["components/UI/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["assets/*"]
    }
```

и пытаюсь заимпортировать файлик

```
    import Input from '@UI/Input/Input' работает
    import Smile from '@assets/svg/Smile'  не работает
    import Smile from '../../../assets/svg/Smile' работает
```

и почему то имеено assets не работает. Components и Assets на одном уровне находятся. В чем ошибка? вдруг важно - это tsx возвращающий svg

Answer (score -1):

```
"baseUrl": "src",
"paths": {
  "components/*": ["components/*"],
  "utils/*": ["utils/*"],
  "UI/*": ["components/UI/*"],
  "assets/*": ["assets/*"]
}
```

попробуйте без "@" должно работать